# ActiveAdmin, Несколько селектов в форме для одного поля таблицы

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как сделать следующее( возможно ли вообще?):
Имеем в таблице бд одно поле типа строка, в форме activeadmin для этого поля несколько селектов, к примеру один со списком цифр, второй букв, а записываться соответственно должно значение вида "1ф".

Comment: вы хотите такую хитрую выборку учинить, типа scope :rogue ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример для модели `User` и поля `full_name` и виртуальных полей `first_name` и `last_name` из которых должно получиться поле `full_name`.

Для начала обманем Formtastic, который все поля берет с модели, иметь нужные поля. Как я понял из условия, "виртуальные" поля там не должны храниться:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  # ...

end
```

В описании темплейта Active Admin перегрузим методы контроллера `create` и `update`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :first_name, :last_name

  # index

  # filters

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :first_name, as: :select, collection: ["Ivan", "Petr"]
      f.input :last_name, as: :select, collection: ["Ivanov", "Petrov"]
    end
  end

  controller do
    def set_full_name first_name, last_name
      @user.full_name = "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
      @user.save
    end

    def create
      create! do
        redirect_to(admin_users_path) and return if set_full_name(params[:user][:first_name], params[:user][:last_name])
      end
    end

    def update
      update! do
        redirect_to(admin_users_path) and return if set_full_name(params[:user][:first_name], params[:user][:last_name])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Пример привел в образовательных целях, в реальном проекте такое лучше не использовать, хотя бы потому, что "виртуальные" поля `first_name` и `last_name` будут всегда обнуляться при каждом построении формы.

Если вы захотите их назначать автоматически и напишете что-то такое:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  def first_name
    full_name.split(' ').first
  end

  def last_name
    full_name.split(' ').last
  end
end
```

То при введении имени из трех слов вы будете парсить неверно. И, конечно же, совсем не сможете правильно распарсить ваш пример с символами и буквами, которые вообще никак не разделяются.

Если подразумевается, что поле `full_name` не будет показываться на сайте, то можно ввести некоторый разделитель в функции конкатенации:

```
def set_full_name first_name, last_name
  @user.full_name = "#{first_name};#{last_name}"
  @user.save
end
```

Возможна еще куча других нюансов, что говорит нам о том, что мы не должны так делать, а лучше бы завести отдельные поля в БД `first_name` и `last_name`.

И еще вариант, если по условию вы можете конкатенировать не только при редактировании в панели администратора, то вместо перегрузки контроллера, можно повесить callback на событие `before_save`:

```
before :save do
  full_name = "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

Внимание! Использование callback-ов не есть хороший стиль программирования. Он может накладывать сложности при тестировании ActiveRecord моделей, когда у вас на элементарные действия будет выполняться очень много кода. Используйте очень осторожно.